# GWT - Cannot see updates in sources via SuperDevMode

Tags: gwt

I am having some troubles in trying out superdevmode. I am working with following technologies:

```
Tomcat 7.0
GWT 2.5.0
Maven
Eclipse
```

I followed instructions to setup superdevmode and finally ran superdevmode using maven -

```
mvn gwt:run-codeserver -Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m"
```

On the browser I loaded:

```
http://localhost:9876/
```

and bookmarked appropriate links. After this, I loaded my app at:

```
https://<ip>:8443/<app-name>
```

Clicked Dev Mode On button -> Compile

I could see code getting compiled on the command line. After successful compilation the page reloads but I don't see my changes or sources in Chrome Sources tab in Developer tools.

Note: I have enabled source maps in settings.

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Trace from Net console:

```
Request
URL:http://localhost:9876/shell/shell.nocache.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request
Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:9876
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
Response
Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Length:9291
Server:Jetty(6.1.x)
```

Comment: Can you check the net tab of your developer tools to determine which server your .nocache.js file is being loaded from, and report back here?

Comment: Are you changing `.java` files or resource files (`.css`, `.ui.xml`, etc.)? It could be related to http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-350

Comment: Java file for one of the views. Regular dev mode through eclipse works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but pressing the reload button yourself sometimes helps.

If that doesn't work, I'd recommend double-checking that you're editing the same file seen by the Super Dev Mode compiler. A good trick is to introduce a syntax error and then verify that the Super Dev Mode compile fails. If it doesn't then you didn't save the file, you're editing the wrong file, or Super Dev Mode is seeing a cached copy of the file somehow. Restarting Super Dev Mode might help.